# Prove $(I + A)v \neq (I + B)(I - C)Av$ for any symmetric & orthogonal matrix $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I would like to show that this holds for any choice of $n\times n$ symmetric and orthogonal matrix $B\neq I, -I$
$$
(I + A)v \neq (I + B)(I - C)Av
$$
where the following are given variables

- $I$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix
- $v\neq 0\in\mathbb{R}^n$
- $A\neq I$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric ($A=A^\top$) and orthogonal $A^\top=A^{-1}$
- $C\neq I$ is an $n\times n$ symmetric ($C=C^\top$) and idempotent $C^2=C$

Comment: Is $A=B=-I$ possible? Then $x=y$.

Comment: Do you really just want to prove the right side is not zero? I don't see the point of adding two extra variables, $x,y.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You’re right I can make the MWE simpler

Comment: Or $C=I, A=-I.$  This is a very strangely written question

Comment: @Euler_Salter MWE?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Minimal Working Example, basically this is a simpler version of a problem I am working on, but solving this will help me solve my actual problem. My bad for writing it poorly, I didn't abstract it enough

Comment: If $v$ is *given* and not a variable parameter, then it is not true that you can simplify by $v$! Think about eigenvalues and eigenvectors: $Ax = \lambda x = (\lambda I)x$ yet $A \neq \lambda I$ in general.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my bad, neither $A$, $B$ or $C$ can be the identity

Comment: @BrunoB $v$ is given indeed, it's fixed. You are right, that's not correct, editing.

Comment: The cases $B=I$ are not the problem. The cases $B=-I$ are the problem.

Comment: (The title should probably be changed now that $x$ and $y$ aren't involved anymore)

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes my bad. I guess what I mean is that I know it is not going to be either $I$ or $-I$

Comment: Oh uh you also don't want $v = 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, just realised

Comment: @BrunoB yep that's also not allowed

Comment: This is not true. Consider
$$
A=B=\pmatrix{-1\\ &1},\,C=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 0&0}
$$
so that $(I+A)-(I+B)(I-C)A=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While a counterexample has been posted in the comments, it's worth remarking that the problem can be simplified signfiicantly.

Symmetric orthogonal matricees only have eigenvalues $-1$ and $1$, and so $I+B$ is symmetric and only has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$, which means it is twice an symmetric idempotent.  Similarly, $I-C$ will also be a symmetric idempotent (if $C$ is orthogonal projection onto a subspace $V$, then $I-C$ is orthogonal projection onto $V^{\perp}$).

So the question simplifies to: If $X, Y$ are non-trivial orthogonal projections, and $A$ is symmetric, then $(2XY-I)Av\neq v$.  However, we will always have equality if $v$ is a common eigenvector of $X, Y, A$ with eigenvalue $1$.

I'm unsure if there are any reasonable restrictions you can place to avoid such a counterexample.

Comment: My bad, where does the $2$ come from in the expression $(2XY - I)Av \neq v$? I recon you have called $Y = I - C$ and $X=I+B$ right?

Comment: @Euler_Salter Almost.  The 2 comes from the fact that I+B has eigenvalues $0$ and $2$, so isn't idempotent, but is rather *twice* an idempotent, so $I+B=2X$